# static array of which items (structs) know where they are in the array

Tags: c, arrays, enums, struct

I have a static array of struct `MyStruct`. I need to access the array by index, but I also need every `MyStruct` to know what its index is. I currently use the following code:

```
enum { INDEX_FOO=0, INDEX_BAR, INDEX_BAZ };
struct MyStruct{ int index; const char* name; /* other data */ };
struct MyStruct values[]={
  { INDEX_FOO, "foo" /* ... */ },
  { INDEX_BAR, "bar" /* ... */ },
  { INDEX_BAZ, "baz" /* ... */ },
};
// requirement: for all i in {0,1,2}: values[i].index==i
```

which however duplicates the enum indices. Is there a way to do this without having to keep the enum and the array in sync?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider [*X-macros*](http://drdobbs.com/184401387) for this.

Something like:

**blah.x**

```
X(FOO, "foo")
X(BAR, "bar")
X(BAZ, "baz")
```

**main.c**

```
#define X(a,b) INDEX_#a,
enum {
#include "blah.x"
};
#undef X

#define X(a,b) { INDEX_#a, b },
struct MyStruct values[]={
#include "blah.x"
};
#undef X
```